# Connection Data Sources and Delegates in Cluttered Interface Builder XIB

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, interface-builder

I am maintaining some code, part of it is a very cluttered xib file with two table views on top of each other (only 1 visible at any time when running) - I need to connect data sources and delegates from each of the tables, but because they're on top of each other, when I drag across, it always picks up the top one. Moving stuff around is not really an option, because it's very cluttered and cramped.

Any ideas on working efficiently with cluttered and complicated xib layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with Xcode 3, look to the small window that shows the main objects, usually File's Owner, First Responder and View.  There's a button on the top left of the window that lets you choose viewing by icons, list, or hierarchical.  If you choose either list or hierarchical view, you can clearly see all your views and subviews in their hierarchical structure.  You can right-click on any of them to make connections.  When you have many views, one on top of another, it's usually much easier to work with them here.

I haven't moved to Xcode 4 yet, but there must be a similar option to view the hierarchical structure of views and subviews.  I hope this helps some.

Comment: Wow - 6 hours of fiddling and trying solved in 30 seconds after your answer - thanks!

Comment: lol, I think I lost more than the 6 hours before I figured that one out.